# Angular 6 lifecycle problem: page gets destroyed apparently with no reason

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lifecycle, destroy, ondestroy

I'm developing a mobile app with Ionic and Angular. I have an issue with Angular lifecycle.
I have a page with a calendar. The calendar has different views: month, week and day. Clicking on a specific day you can see events that occurr in that day. Clicking on the event the app goes to a page with event details. From this detail page there is a link to go back to the calendar.

The problem I am facing is this: sometimes when i go to an event detail page the calendar page gets destroyed, so when i come back to the calendar, the calendar is re-initialized to the defaults (focus on today and week view). This happens only sometimes and I can't understand why.

I thought the page was destroyed only if changing url parameters. For example: the user can see more calendars, which id is passed in the url; I understand that the calendar page gets destroyed and re-initialized when changing calendar. The problem is that sometimes this happens even within the same calendar when opening and event and then coming back to the calendar page. As I said this doesn't happen every time, but only sometimes, and I can't find a pattern.
To go back to de calendar page, from the event page, i simply do this:

```
 goToCalendar() {
        if (this.userId) {
          this.router.navigate(['/calendar/view/user/', this.userId]);
        } else {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/calendar/view');
        }

  }
```

Can you help me understand?
Thanks,
Sabrina

Comment: which ionic version are you using?

Comment: can you please provide a stackblit? without complete details it will be guess work.

Comment: @Arikael I am using ionic 4.11.10

Answer (score 1):

store in a service the data and use in ngOnDestroy to store the variable and ngOnInit to recover it

Imagine you has a service like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ShareService{

  data:any={}
  constructor() { }

}
```

And you want "remember" a variable date

In your page.calendar.component

```
date=new Date()
constructor(private shareService:ShareService){}
ngOnInit()
{
    if (this.shareService.data.date)
        this.date=this.shareService.data.date
}
ngOnDestroy()
{
    this.shareService.data.date=this.date
}
```